# Parameterized Query PHP/SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a web form that enters event details into a database to be listed on a website. The form captures the name of a photo, event title, a date to unlist the event, a sort number, a description, and a bit flag "Mass".

The description field is a plain text field. I know that I should probably change the field to rich text, but that is for a day when I have time to explore how to do that. Anyways... I've been adding HTML characters into my text to format it. I find that the slash of closing characters like < / strong> is being treated as an escape character rather than part of the text. How do I tell my code to not escape?

The code:

```
//connect to the database.
$serverName = "livedata";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"administration", "UID"=>"User", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD", "LoginTimeout"=>60 );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Set up the parameterized query. */  
$tsql = "insert into tblevents (Photo, title, Unlist, Sort, Description, Par_num, mass ) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  

/* Set parameter values. */  
$dt = $_POST['unlist'];
if ($dt == ""){
    $dt = null; 
}
$Sort = $_POST['sort'];
if ($Sort == "" ){
//query to get the max of sort in the database items
//+1 sort

    $sql2 = "SELECT tblevents.Par_Num, Max(tblevents.Sort) AS MaxOfSort FROM parishevents.dbo.tblevents GROUP BY tblevents.Par_Num HAVING (((tblevents.Par_Num)=" . $_POST['par_num'] . "));";
        //echo "SQL2: " . $sql2 . "<br><br>";

    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
    if( $stmt2 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
    while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2)) { 
        $Sort = $row2['MaxOfSort'] +1;
}
    if(isset($_POST['mass'])){
        if($_POST['mass'] == "on"){
            $mass = -1;
        }
        else{
            $mass = 0;
        }
    }else{
        $mass = 0;  
    }
$params = array($_POST['photo'], $_POST['title'], $dt, $Sort, $_POST['description'], $_POST['par_num'], $mass);  

/* Prepare and execute the query. */  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);  


/* Free statement and connection resources. */  
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);  

}
```

Comment: You might want to take a peek at your query. HAVING is used to filter groups, WHERE is used to filter rows (which is what you are trying to do here).

Comment: For the question at hand I don't understand what you are having an issue with but I am pretty sure it isn't a sql server thing.

Comment: Before posting my question...I was getting a PHP warning and the record was not being written to the database. I just tried it again and now I get a different warning: PHP Warning:  sqlsrv_free_stmt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in add_event.php on line 59. I commented out the line and the warning went away, but what does the warning mean?

Comment: @RCDAWebmaster The warning is clear - `$stmt` is `false`after `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);` call. Please, include error check `if( $stmt === false ) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}` and if possible, post error message.

Comment: I added the code and got no error message. I made sure to uncomment the line that was tossing the warning. Now the page works. I don't know why.

Comment: I checked my query in Access and It tosses a syntax error if I use WHERE. I need to use HAVING since I'm finding the max sort value of events at a particular location.